# iOS NSComparisonresult issue

Tags: objective-c, ios, comparison

It raises an exception when I enter more than two characters in the searchfield. I use NSComparisonResult to show results on a UITableView:

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText
{

for (mystring in self.array)
{

NSComparisonResult result = [mystring compare:searchText options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch) 
range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchText length])];

if (result == NSOrderedSame)
        {   
            NSUInteger index=[self.array indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:mystring]; 
            NSUInteger maxindex = index + 50;
            for (index ; (index < [self.array count] && index <= maxindex && index!= NSNotFound); index ++)
            {   
                [self.filteredListContent addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[self.array objectAtIndex:index],@"english",[self.secondarray objectAtIndex:index],@"translated",nil]];  
            }
            break;
        }
}
```

The output shows:

```
 -[UIDeviceWhiteColor compare:options:range:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5e4a5d0
2011-11-06 12:10:51.932 XXX[2583:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIDeviceWhiteColor compare:options:range:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5e4a5d0'
```

What does UIDeviceWhiteColor in this case mean?

---

```
self.array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:
           [[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"first" ofType:@"txt"]
                                      encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL] componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]];

self.secondarray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:
           [[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"second" ofType:@"txt"]
                                      encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL] componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because there is a `UIDeviceWhiteColor` somewhere in your `self.array`, which should be made of just `NSString`s. How do you populate this array?

Comment: please see my edit. I populate both arrays with at least one string and maximum three strings. How come?

Comment: Isn't your array re-assigned somewhere else? What about doing a `NSLog(@"self.array: %@", self.array);` at the beginning of your `filterContentForSearchText`, what does it output?

Comment: self.array is nonatomic,retain as well. NSLog showed three rounds of whole self.array before it crashes when result == NSOrderedSame is being used. NSLog showed only strings and some numbers from self.array.

Answer (score 1):

There's a `UIDeviceWhiteColor` object in `self.array`. You should also cast `mystring` as an `NSString` or whatever kind of object it is. If you'd cast it in `UIDeviceWhiteColor` then the compiler would give you a warning that `UIDeviceWhiteColor` **does not** respond to `compare:options:range:`.

```
for (NSString *mystring in self.array)
{
    //some code
}
```

Comment: What does UIDeviceWhiteColor object look like? A certain string? mystring is a global string which is nonatomic, retain in .h and synthesized in .m.

Comment: Wait, `mystring` is already declared and synthesized? Then you should not use it in your loop!

Comment: @jef it is 13000 strings... but i will try another smaller array and post the result of array.

Comment: Yes, `myString` could be the `UIDeviceWhiteColor`.

Comment: @Jef There is no UIDeviceWhiteColor in my two arrays.

Comment: Yep, be careful when you write loops, not to use a variable already defined somewhere else… glad to have helped.